# XUL/Thunderbird: startEditing return

Tags: javascript, xul, thunderbird

I'm playing with the thunderbird codebase, the aim being to implement inline contact editing. The current code catches the `Click` event on a `XUL` tree, and if it's a double click (`events.detail == 2`), it open the profile editor. I modified it so as to start editing the current `treeCell`, and I did add `editable=true` to the corresponding `XUL` document. The updated code reads

```
var orow = {}, ocolumn = {}, opart = {};
gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.getCellAt(event.clientX, event.clientY,
                                       orow, ocolumn, opart);

var row = orow.value, column = ocolumn.value.index;         
if (row == -1) 
  return;

if (event.detail == 2)
  gAbResultsTree.startEditing(row, column);
```

Unfortunately, when the code reaches the `startEditing` part, it returns

`Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) [nsITreeView.isEditable]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/tree.xml :: startEditing :: line 337"  data: no]`

I'm pretty much lost here. Could someone with more XUL experience help?
Thanks!

Comment: Side question: Thunderbird seems to cache script files: when I create a new profile, all changes to tb script files are registered correctly. But then no further changes are applied. So if I make modifications to the js source after creating a profile, I have to recreate a new one for these new changes to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to do something similar and I have same problem.

Wrapper with original abview set as `__proto__` with functions overriden works fine until it is set as abResultsTree's view.

I've finally found (I hope) an elegant solution.

```
function MyAbView() {
    this.originalAbViewInstance = this.originalAbViewFactory.createInstance(null, Ci.nsIAbView);

    if (!this.proxiesGenerated) {
        // find out which interfaces are implemented by original instance, their property proxies will be generated later
        for (var ifName in Ci) {
            if (Ci[ifName] instanceof Ci.nsIJSID && this.originalAbViewInstance instanceof Ci[ifName]) {
                MyAbView.prototype.supportedInterfaces.push(Ci[ifName]);
            }
        }

        function generatePropertyProxy(name) {
            Object.defineProperty(MyAbView.prototype, name, {
                get: function() {
                    return this.originalAbViewInstance[name];
                },
                set: function(val) {
                    this.originalAbViewInstance[name] = val;
                },
                enumerable: true
            });
        }

        for (var prop in this.originalAbViewInstance) {
            if (this[prop] == undefined) {
                generatePropertyProxy(prop);
            }
        }

        MyAbView.prototype.proxiesGenerated = true;
    } else {
        for each (var interface in this.supportedInterfaces) {
            this.originalAbViewInstance.QueryInterface(interface);
        }
    }
}

MyAbView.prototype = {
    classID: null,

    _xpcom_factory: {
        createInstance: function(outer, iid) {
            return new MyAbView().QueryInterface(iid);
        }
    },

    QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
        for each (var interface in this.supportedInterfaces) {
            if (interface.equals(aIID)) {
                return this;
            }
        }

        throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;
    },

    originalAbViewFactory: null,
    originalAbViewInstance: null,

    proxiesGenerated: false,
    supportedInterfaces: [],

    // any overriden functions come here
};
```

It's implemented as a component to replace the original abview, but it might be modified to just create a wrapper.

Comment: Thanks David. Could you expand a little on how this code works?

Comment: Basically it's:
1. create instance of original abview
2. find all interfaces implemented by abview
3. create abview wrapper:
  -define its `QueryInterface` function, in case interface is supported it has to return the wrapper, not wrapped instance
  -define any functions/properties you want to override
  -other functions/properties will be used from the wrapped instance (this is achieved by the `generatePropertyProxy` function)

Comment: `generatePropertyProxy` is the most tricky step, this way it acts similar as wrapped instance would be set as wrapper's prototype, but it doesn't break as if `__proto__` is used

Answer (score 1):

The `<tree>` widget uses an [nsITreeView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsITreeView) object to retrieve or manipulate data that needs to be displayed. There are predefined `nsITreeView` implementations reading data from the DOM or RDF datasources but one can choose to use his own tree view. Thunderbird's address book chooses the latter:

```js
gAbView = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/addressbook/abview;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIAbView);

...

gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view =
  gAbView.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsITreeView);
```

Unfortunately for you, the component in question is implemented in C++, in the file [nsAbView.cpp](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/addrbook/src/nsAbView.cpp). This means that changing it without recompiling Thunderbird isn't possible. And the existing component doesn't implement `isEditable()` and `setCellText()` methods that would be required to edit tree cells.

If you don't want to mess with C++ yet, you could wrap that component in your own object. Something like this:

```js
gAbView = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/addressbook/abview;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIAbView);
gAbViewWrapper = {
  __proto__: gAbView,
  QueryInterface: function(iid)
  {
    gAbView.QueryInterface(iid);
    return this;
  },
  isEditable: function(row, col)
  {
    // Do something here
  },
  setCellText: function(row, col, value)
  {
    // Do something here
  }
};

...

gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view =
  gAbViewWrapper.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsITreeView);
```

Method `isEditable()` should check again whether this particular cell is editable - even if the column is editable, individual cells don't have to be. And `setCellText()` should store the new value for the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot =) Just one question: what is the affectation for in `gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view = gAbViewWrapper.QueryInterface(...)`? If `QueryInterface` returns something, then what does the call in `gAbViewWrapper` do?

Comment: I've tried this method, but I can't get it to work. It seems that the IsEditable function in gAbViewWrapper is never called :/

Comment: @Clément: The method is called `isEditable()` in JavaScript, it is only `IsEditable()` in C++. Concerning `QueryInterface()` see [JavaScript tips](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_Tips#XPConnect) - using the return value isn't necessary in JavaScript, the call modifies the original object. The call in `gAbResultsTree` makes sure that the original object implements this interface - if it doesn't then the call will throw an exception and no value will be returned.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my comment. I did use isEditable in my js code, but still no luck. I posted my `abResultsPane.js` on http://pastebin.com/jqbL3wHF . Could you have a look? I really can't see what I'm doing wrong :/

Comment: @Clément: First of all, you obviously need to declare `gAbViewWrapper` (below `var gAbView = null` would make sense). You shouldn't create a new instance every time `SetAbView()` is called, only the first time - add wrapper creation to the `if (!gAbView)` block above. Finally, `alert()` is not defined in XPCOM components, use `Components.utils.reportError()` and check Error Console.

Comment: Thanks. Just to see if I understand correctly, this means that `gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view = gAbViewWrapper.QueryInterface(...)` is a shorter way of writing `gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view = gAbViewWrapper; gAbViewWrapper.QueryInterface(...)`, all right?

Comment: @Clément: The other way round: `gAbViewWrapper.QueryInterface(...); gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view = gAbViewWrapper;`. But - yes.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really having trouble with this. I updated my code (http://pastebin.com/FAiFNMiN), and calling `gAbViewWrapper.isEditable` directly works perfectly. When I call `gAbResultsTree.treeBoxObject.view.isEditable`, though, I get the same error as before. Same when I call startEditing. Any idea? Thanks again.